# Which regression models should be used with very tiny dataset?

Tags: regression, model-selection

I have a very tiny dataset to make a regression model. only 22 data points with just 2 float features and 1 float output.
I want to make models among `sklearn` available models. and a little confused because I had never deal with such a tiny data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That dataset might be too small for machine learning. You will not be able to do a train/test split.

If you still choose to try machine learning, choose a model that has very few parameters. Two options are:

1. [Linear Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) - Fit only an intercept and two coefficients (one for each feature) at most. Do not add any interaction or polynomial coefficients.
2. [Decision Tree Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_tree_regression.html) - Fit a model with a very small `max_depth`. For example, a decision stump has a `max_depth` of 1, aka a single split.

Answer (score 2):

The main risk with a very small dataset is overfitting. The more complex a model is, the more likely it is to overfit with a small training set. In order to minimize the risk you could use a very simple model (linear regression comes to mind). Note that you can also try other methods and check for overfitting by comparing the performance on the training set and the test set.